# Using css Ellipsis on inline or inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have 2 inline element and they are wrapped by div(block) element.

The div width is fixed, and the 2 child inline element contents length are vary.

and I want ellipsis on the 2nd child content, and it depends on the first child element's length.

Ex)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">This should be displayed all + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">Short + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">depends on left size + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>
```

expected:

```
This should be displayed all + This content ...
Short + This content should be ellipsised
depends on left size + This content should ...
```

So it seems like ellipsis on wrapper, if the content of wrapper is longer than wrapper with, I want to ellipsis the wrapper's child content.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please add your CSS code? I could probably figure it out, I need to know your styles though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `text-overflow: ellipsis`:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

```css
.wrapper{
width:300px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.left,.right{
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">This should be displayed all + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">Short + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="left">depends on left size + </p>
    <p class="right">This content should be ellipsised </p>
<div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, the problem was one of the child element wasn't inline element, it was h4 which is block element ;p